# Scaling AlignedBox

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a dummy question. Should the two codes below give the same results ? (scaling the bb by 1.5)

init:

```
 Eigen::AlignedBox3d bb(Eigen::Vector3d(0.,0.,0.), Eigen::Vector3d(8753.82,9283.96,1050.49))
```

first:

```
 Eigen::Vector3d center = bb.center();
 Eigen::Vector3d r = bb.diagonal()/2.;

 bb.min() = center - 1.5 * r;
 bb.max() = center + 1.5 * r;
```

second:

```
 bb.transform(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, Eigen::Affine>(Eigen::UniformScaling(1.5)));
```

I don't have the same results in my code..
To be more precise:
With the bb:

- minbb: 0 0 0
- maxbb: 8753.82 9283.96 1050.49

The first version gives me:

- minbb: -2188.46 -2320.99 -262.624
- maxbb: 10942.3 11604.9 1313.12

The second version:

- minbb: 0 0 0
- maxbb: 13130.7 13925.9 1575.74

Comment: The difference is greater than floating point arithmetics

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your provided code, I cannot see whether the bounding box is initialised correctly.

Comment: I am giving the parameters but ok

Comment: Generally, a reproducible example is preferred. Personally, I think that your question is clear enough this way, too. However, I can see that you added the parameters after my comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, they should not give the same results. To “transform” a solid object or other geometric set, you transform each point contained in it. There is no point in your box which, when uniformly scaled by a factor of 1.5, results in negative coordinates, because there is no point in the box which has negative coordinates in the first place.

It sounds like you’re thinking of a bonding box as having a “local origin” at its center, and expecting the transformation to be applied in local space. But the box has no inherent origin, and in any case, the transform is applied directly to the object.

Comment: But a transform is applied to the box. The box is somehow scaled starting from the min instead of the center. The center is moving so the "local origin" is the min of the bounding box ?

Comment: No, there is no "local origin". The transform is applied to the box, not in a coordinate system defined by the box, but in a coordinate system defined by the world. (*The* coordinate system.) "Scale by 1.5" means "multiply everything by 1.5", just as "translate by (1,0,0)" would mean "add 1 to everything's X coordinate", regardless of which way each object was facing.

Comment: What I wanted to say is: Is this not a particular case because the min is (0.0.0). If I had negative values. The bb scaled on each axes in the positive and negative values ?